# R ifelse sequence always 0

Tags: r, if-statement, sequence

I want to have a sequence for a certain case. For this I use an ifelse statement, but I always receive zero. Here is a simple example:

```
seq(0,10, by=1)
[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

while

```
ifelse (1==1, seq(0,10, by=1), seq(0,10, by=1))
[1] 0
```

I don't see, why I would get 0 in the second case.

Best,

Mat

Comment: `ifelse` works on a vector. The test is executed on each element (first part, where you have `1==1`), and if `TRUE`, returns second part, or if `FALSE`, third part. Something along the lines of `x <- 1:10;ifelse(x <= 5, NA, x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first argument is of length one - so the output will be of length 1.  It is true, so is returning the first element of your second argument, which is 0.

Maybe you want

```
if (1==1) {
seq(0,10, by=1)
} else {
seq(0,10, by=1)
}
```

Neither is a very realistic piece of code, though

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand the use of ifelse completely. Your condition (1 == 1) is always true, so you know the answer in advance. Moreover the result for positive and negative examples is the same.

You use `ifelse` to test a vector on a certain condition. If a value in the vector abides to the condition the first value is returned, if it doesn't the second one is returned. For example;

```
test <- sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = T) 
ifelse(test == "a", 'is a', 'is b')
```

The result will always be of the same length as the input vector. If your return values have a length longer than 1, the `ifelse` will be aborted if the length of the input vector is reached. This implies that values in the import vector remain unevaluated. So you typically don't want to use the `ifelse` when your return values are longer than 1.

Comment: I am aware if the usage of ifelse. This was just an example to trigger the sequence. The original code is a lot more complicated than that.